# after python 2.7 installation version still showing as 2.6.5

Tags: windows, python-2.7, windows-7

I am using 64 bit window 7 version.
Recently installed python 2.7 and was able to see python27 folder inside C drive.
I even update environment variable to use C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts.

python --version
Python 2.6.5

which python
/usr/bin/python

How can i update system to use python 2.7 version?

Answer (score 0):

Need more explanation.

1. Like from where you have downloaded the Python package binary?
2. What was installation path when you have installed it?
3. What was Python 2.6.5 installation path?
4. Does old environment variable still present?